# Node.js: How to call a function2 after function1?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have two functions (cb() and cb1()) that needs to be call one after the other.

If I simply do `cb(); cb1();` that won't work so I tried to call `cb1();` when `cb();` finishes, as this:

```
 cb = function(err) {
    if (err)
    die(err);
    else if (next < cmds.length){
    cmds[next++].apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments).slice(1));
    console.log(next);
    }
    else 
    cb1();
};
```

However, the function is not being called. What am I missing here? I understand that because the code is async, the functions are not called one after the other in my first try. Am I right?

Thanks!

Comment: That style of coding looks alien to javascript. I suspect there's a better way of doing what you want to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to ensure one thing is called after another try this :

```
cb();
process.nextTick(cb1);
```

[`process.nextTick`](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.5/api/all.html#process.nextTick)

Like I mentioned your block of code feels like emulating a different language in javascript. What are you trying to achieve from a high level point of view? There may be a better way of handling this.